# Using 'this' and jQuery methods (parent) in CoffeScript (converting jQuery to CoffeeScript)

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

First time using CoffeeScript so apologies if this is a basic question, but a quick google failed me.

Upon clicking a link i want to grab the

My HTML:

```
<td class="value-ignore" data-report-item="1">
    <a href="/report_item_ignores/new" data-remote="true">New ignore</a>
</td>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('td.value-ignore a').click(function(){
    var id = this.parent().attr('data-report-item')
    console.log(id)
});
```

My CoffeScript (attempt):

```
$ ->
  $('td.value-ignore a').click ->
    id = @parent().attr('data-report-item')
    console.log id
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object http://example has no method 'parent'
```

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: I believe there is the same error in plain old js... Don't you need to wrap `this` with jQuery: `$(this).parent()`

Comment: Ah how stupid of me - yes that's perfect. Thank you

Comment: if you're doing @parent() etc you need to get acquained with the "fat" arrow: =>. It "can be used to both define a function, and to bind it to the current value of this, right on the spot." It stores the parent object in a _this variable and makes any subsequent "this" calls to _this instead.

Comment: Has my answer helped you? would you consider marking as correct?

Comment: Well it was actually @YuryTarabanko who answered my question, but for the sake of having questions marked as answered i will accept yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $('td.value-ignore a').click ->
    id = $(this).parent().attr('data-report-item')
    console.log id
```